# React component in TypeScript if passed as parameter and assigned to variable; TS2604: JSX element type does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, tsx

I'm trying to hanlde props of passed React Element in Factory but I cannot because I receive typescript error:

```
TS2604: JSX element type 'this.extraBlock' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

My Child component:

```
interface BlockTitleType {
  title: string,
  children?: React.ReactNode
}

const MainContactBlock: React.FC<BlockTitleType> = (e: BlockTitleType) => <div>{e.title}</div>;
```

My Parent component:

```
const factory = new TabBlockFactory(MainContactBlock);

const ContactBlocks: React.FC = () => <>factory.createBlock('test title')}</>
```

My factory:

```
interface BlockType {
  title: string
}

class TabBlockFactory {
  private mainBlock: React.ReactNode;

  constructor(mainBloc: React.FC) {
    this.mainBlock = mainBloc;
  }

  createBlock = ({title}: BlockType) => {
// the error occurs here: 
// TS2604: JSX element type 'this.extraBlock' does not have any construct or call signatures.
   return <this.mainBlock title={title}/>
  }
}
```

it works only with any type, but it's an antipatern :(

#### Update:

I also tried types as *React.Component, React.ReactElement, JSX.Elements*

I've tried all 3 fixes from @Yuval:

1. Has no effect - renamed class variable `this.mainBlock -> this.MainBlock`;
2. Has no effect - introduced intermediate variable

```
const Component = this.mainBloc;
return <Component title={title} />;
```

3. Successfully helped me - `private MainBlock: React.ComponentType<BlockTitleType>;` as @Yuval proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: [working sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-resonance-lwn6j?file=/src/App.tsx)

So there is a few problems with your code:

1. you are using the type `React.ReactNode` to represent a component, and it doesn't work. I recommend that to represent a React Component you use `React.ComponentType<PROPS>`.
   So in your case in will be `ComponentType<BlockTitleType>`
2. the line `<this.mainBlock />` is problematic, react doesn't like Components that do not start with an Upper case and also its an access to a `this` attribute at the same time, so separate that into 2 lines like so:

```
const Component = this.mainBloc;
return <Component title={title} />;
```

3. other than that I added some small syntax fixes and small improvements

   - quick assignment and declaration in the Factory class
   - missing `{` in `ContactBlocks`

Comment: thanks, 2 your fixed made no effect (intermediate variable and camel-case, but **ComponentType<BLockTitleType>** did help